# Transpiling dynamic ES6 System.import to ES5 (amd or other)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, amd, code-translation, systemjs

I'm stuck with dynamic requering es6 modules by invoking them through:

```
System.import('SOME_PATH').then(function (MODULE_FROM_SOME_PATH) {});
```

It works well with `es6-module-loader` and babel runtime compilation in browser, but when i want to precompile it to `ES5` syntax (for production uses) it just passes `System.import` expression in code, leaving in practically untouched, just replacing `System.import` with equivalent `System['import']`.

I've tried `gulp-babel` and babel `npm` package. So when opened in browser it gives expected module loading error. How can i transpile my code to `AMD` syntax for `ES5`. Hoping for your help.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to do - is the aim to load modules that have been transcompiled to ES5, in which case the modules will have to be transcompiled to System.register modules.

Comment: Do you mean changing System.import('aModule').then(fn) to require(['aModule'], fn)? Or even better, something equivalent but more UMD like?

Answer (score 0):

Just pushed [babel-plugin-system-import-transformer](https://github.com/thgreasi/babel-plugin-system-import-transformer) that replaces System.import to the equivalent UMD import (AMD, CommonnJS & Global module imports).

I have also created a [separate localforage branch](https://github.com/thgreasi/localForage/tree/es6-babel-system-import) that uses System.import statements as an example.

Hope this helps.